# Is it safe to store the state of a game in Javascripts localStorage?

Tags: javascript, savegame

I am going to be completely honest, this is not 100% about storing a game state in Javascript's localStorage, it is more to do with a utility program storing statistics. Since it can be related to games I am asking here, rather than on StackOverflow which is more to do with coding. I know how to code it.

My worry is this. I want a person to store their statistics for a web-app in localStorage. It will be stats they could be collecting over a year or so. It will be saved automatically so they do not have to worry about a thing.

The problem I have is they can accidently, without knowing it, delete these statistics when they delete cookies when they delete the browser's history.

Most web-app users are not experts and will not know they are deleting their localStorage for my Stats-Web-App when they delete all their other browser history.

**What can I do to make this safe?**

I could obviously let them save to the File/Directory system (which I also know how to code), but that is more cumbersome for them and through experience I find they often forget.

I just do not know what is considered best practices.

For a game, if they lost their save, its just a bit of bad luck. Maybe a week or so play. But for stats they have been collecting for a year, it could be soul destroying.

I value your opinion.

Comment: "For a game, if they lost their save, its just a bit of bad luck. ... But for stats they have been collecting for a year, it could be soul destroying." I think you've accurately identified why game developers are likely to have a different take on this than what you really need, and you should ask developers of apps that hold sensitive / irreplaceable long-term data instead. Those developers can be found on StackOverflow or the Database Administrators StackExchange. Please ask here when you need help with something unique to games, which storing persistent data in a web app is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that this question doesn't really belong in the Game Development stack exchange, but it doesn't really matter.

In general treat local storage as temporary. Nothing that needs to persist for long periods of time should be stored there.

The way I see it you have two options:

1. Do the local file saving thing you mentioned
2. Use some sort of database (probably a BaaS such as Supabase or Firebase)

Option two will provide more versatility over option one but will take more time to implement.